# Which tools do you use as malware scan for your site files?

Tags: malware

my non-wordpress site has been attacked by malware. I want to let scan zipped version off all files but I don't know any tools able to do that.

For Wordpress I use Wordfence plugin. Wordfence launched last year now defunct 'Gravityscan' fow malware scan.

Do you know any similar service for non-wordpress sites able to detect malware from zip dump of the root?

Comment: If your server is Linux based, maldet (Linux Malware Detect) is a reasonable choice. Many leading hosting providers use that.

Comment: ClamAV is another for Linux.

Comment: @closetnoc do you use any special custom malware signatures or just pure clamav?

Comment: I just use ClamAV as it is. I do not allow up loading.